# passing array as parameter of RunPython script in VBA (xlwings)

Tags: python, arrays, excel, vba, xlwings

In my VBA sub, I'm calling a python script using the command RunPython from xlwings. I would like to call a function that takes an array as parameter. How can I convert the VBA data type into a list readable by Python?

Code:

```
RunPython("import script; script.query(dates=argsArray, queryString='"& myString &"')
```

I can successfully pass a string using &, although i don't know how to pass the array argsArray as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at converters.

http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html?highlight=array

What you can do is pass the Range address as a string and then get the values as as an array.  From the documentation:

```
arr = xw.Range('A1:A3').options(np.array, ndim=2).value
```

where you would replace 'A1:A3' with argsArrayAddressString:

```
RunPython("import script; script.query(dates=argsArrayAddressString, queryString='"& myString &"')
```

then in your code:

```
arr = xw.Range(argsArrayAddressString).options(np.array, ndim=2).value
```

Comment: Sounds good, although in my UDF signature  in VBA, should argsArrayAddressString be of type Range?

Comment: In this case it would be a string "A1:A3" which is then used to construct a range.  Python called this way will not understand a VBA range object.  If you want to get more complicated, UDF's can be made with decorators defining ranges as numpy arrays.  see here: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html#function-arguments-and-return-values.  and also see here: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html

Comment: I know, any ways thank you I appreciate your efforts. I guess I'm mostly trying to pass arguments other than strings to functions within my RunPython script.